# tried putting this <link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>"> as canonical tag

Tags: rel-canonical

This message pop up at dashboard "Your website URL has recently been changed. Automatic payments and customer emails have been disabled to prevent live transactions originating from development or staging servers." As i am new in this field so i don't have any idea what should i do to solve this.

Comment: What's the point of setting the canonical URL to the current URL?

Comment: So that by clicking any linking like https://www.example.com , https://example.com or be it any other link all should open to a single url to https://www.example.com. It helps to remove the duplication of site and the site can rank good in search engine.

Comment: What's displaying that message? WordPress doesn't have live transactions etc